# Describe the distribution measure of a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Considering a discrete probability space $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,...\}$ such that

$$P(\{n\}) = (1-q) \ q^n$$

where $P$ denotes the probability measure and $q$ is a fixed number from the interval $(0,1)$ and $\epsilon: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable such that

$$\epsilon(n) = (-1)^n$$

How can I describe the distribution measure of $\epsilon$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

I am not sure I understand it correctly, but I assume that the possible outcomes are $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,...\}$ and for every possible outcome there is a probability $P(\{n\}) = (1-q) \ q^n$ for it to occur.

But I don't know what it means that $\epsilon(n) = (-1)^n$ and how to sufficiently describe the distribution measure of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

$\epsilon$ takes only the values -1 and +1. it takes the value +1 on the set $\{0,2,4,...\}$ and -1 on $\{1,3,5,...\}$. $P\{\epsilon =1\}=\sum_n P(\{2n\})=\sum_n (1-q)q^{2n}=\frac {1-q} {1-q^{2}}=\frac 1 {1+q}$ and $\epsilon = -1\}= \sum_n (1-q)q^{2n-1}=\frac q {1+q}$.

Comment: I do understand that $\epsilon$ is defined on $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ and that it can only take values $-1$ and $+1$, but I don't see how it is related to the probability function $P(\{n\})$ and also what $P(\{n\})$ actually means, i.e. what is the difference between $P(n)$ and $P(\{n\})$.

Comment: The sample space is $\{0,1,2,..\}$ and $P$ is a probability measure defined on the sigma algebra of all subsets of the sample space. $P$ is specified by the formula $P\{n\}=(1-q)q^{n}$ which means the probability of any event $A \subset \{0,1,2,...\}$ is obtained by adding $P\{n\}$ over all $n \in A$. $\epsilon$ is a functions from the sample space to $\mathbb R$. Since it takes only the values 1 and -1 we can specify its distribution by just the probabilities of the events $\{\epsilon =1\}$ and $\{\epsilon =-1\}$